# Can I change the width of a textfield in webapp

Tags: html-input, webapp-net

I am making an app for iOS, Android, BB, and also any other devices. I am working with webapp-net.
In my app, I have a fieldset containing different text fields. So this is what I have:

```
<fieldset>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="text" id="cc" placeholder="Card Number" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="23"/></li>
        <li><input type="text" id="chn" placeholder="Holder Name" autocomplete="off" /></li>
        <li><input type="text" id="cvc" placeholder="CSC" autocomplete="off" maxlength="4" /></li>
</fieldset>
```

For CSC, I need it to be only for 4 numbers, but I can't change the width. I also want to be able to create a pop up/dialog box, so when you click on CSC a box will appear with a little information about CSC.

I tried, but I can't even change the width. So if you know how to fix this problem please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `size` attribute :

```
<input type="text" maxlength="4" size="4" />
```